# Public GETH trace

Tags: go-ethereum, transaction-trace

On Etherscan we can see geth traces, but only for 1000 operations for some reason. Is there any site where we can do geth traces or is there a public geth node where we can do these traces?

Comment: what traces exactly are you talking about?

Comment: Example https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x56bb53dac9073d46e3a3b716ca44655fcd15487c528dcf2fa3c320a8368a0ad9

Comment: the example you are showing has RETURN at the end, this means contract exited. execution.

Comment: also, how do you know that there is more opcodes to execute instead of 1,000 ??

Comment: I'm sorry I used an example where no more than 1000 opcodes are shown. I don't care if the code executes or not, I'd like GETH traces to do some analysis (mainly on gas usage). Example which has more than 1000 ops but only shows 1000: https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x8af62ab2ab8651ec5cbdd04531ed4a2e9ed9b2d58fe47f2da28e57bfab02fe4b